# Enterprise Library 4.1 Apps and Enterprise Library 5 apps run on the same server?

Tags: enterprise-library

Are there any issues with having some apps utilizing EL 4.1 and some 5?  Meaning if I decide that a new app will use 5.0 and the majority of the web apps existing is using 4.1, when I deploy to production or even in any situation would there be conflicts or problems if you have apps using different versions?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use multiple versions in the *same* application, but I have never had an issue using multiple versions of Enterprise Library in separate applications. There is only one thing I can think of that you might need to watch out for. If any of the web applications using the new version is a child of another using the old version, you might run into some issues due to configuration inheritance.